# gcc warning flag at the end of warning output. what does it mean?

Tags: c, gcc

I want to know what does the warning flag at the end of warning statement (in compilation output) shows ?

e.g in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g_var = 'ghij';

int
main(void)
{
fprintf(stderr," g_var = %d " , g_var);
return 0;
}
```

when compiled with

```
gcc temp.c
```

compilation shows this output

> temp.c:3:13: warning: multi-character character constant **[-Wmultichar]**

what does the `-Wmultichar` at the end has to say ?

**EDIT:** I understant why this warning is there but I want to know the meaning of this flag e.g how can this flag be used to remove this warning ?

Comment: Huh? When compiling using `gcc temp.c`, GCC will not emit a warning. You need `-Wmultichar` to `-Wall` (which enables other warning flags like `-Wmultichar`) to see the warning

Comment: gcc version 4.8.2 does... and believe me my friend m not lying :)

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.8.1 . It does not warn me. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does the `-Wmultichar` at the end has to say ?

It indicates that that's the specific flag which enables this warning. Often, you'll enable multiple warnings with `-Wall` or `-Wextra`, and it can be useful to know where each warning came from, for example if you want to disable just one warning.

> how can this flag be used to remove this warning ?

Add `-Wno-multichar` to the compiler options, after any options that enable warnings, to disable this warning.

Comment: I did not enabled any warning flag ... there should be some defaults which gcc uses ... how can i find them +1 for your answer

Comment: @theadnangondal: If you look at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), any option listed as `-Wno-whatever` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

This is indicating the specific warning flag which was enabled and found an issue in your code.

The actual issue is that you have more than one character in a character constant: `'ghij'`

If you wanted to turn off that warning for some reason, you would use `-Wno-multichar`.

If you wanted to treat warnings like this as errors, pass `-Werror`.

Answer (score 2):

`multichar` is one of the options supplied with `gcc` to **"Request or Suppress Warnings"**

- `-Wmultichar` is used to **turn ON** the warning.
- `-Wno-multichar` is used to **turn OFF** the warning.

From the [gcc online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

> `-Wno-multichar`
>
> Do not warn if a multicharacter constant (`'FOOF'`) is used. Usually they indicate a typo in the user's code, as they have implementation-defined values, and should not be used in portable code.